# How do you add a .swf streaming video to a web page from a home server?

Tags: ubuntu, webserver, webcam, motion

I have a linux box server running at home. It is behind a route that I have enabled port forwarding. I want the web page it displays to contain an object/video/whatever that displays my web cam's image. The webcam feed is being ran by Motion. Locally (before involving the router) I can connect to the correct port but no image is displayed. Externally (involving the router) I am unable to connect. There is possibly 2 problems here, one with the port forwarding, and one with the Motion configuration. Anyone ever done this before?

Comment: There are a few things you need to do. First make sure you can access data on the correct port on the server box with `curl localhost:portNumber`. If that works then try the same thing with your remote machine with `curl serverIP:portNumber`. And for both of those the portNumber is whatever port you designated in motion.conf. If both of those still work then we are in business. I used Cambozola as an applet in my webpage to handle the .swf file that Motion streams out.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you need to do. First make sure you can access data on the correct port on the server box with `curl localhost:portNumber`. If that works then try the same thing with your remote machine with `curl serverIP:portNumber`. And for both of those the portNumber is whatever port you designated in motion.conf. If both of those still work then we are in business. I used Cambozola as an applet in my webpage to handle the .swf file that Motion streams out.